# Kafka Elasticsearch Sink Connector: Connection Error

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am new to using Kafka and Kafka Connectors. I have been trying to use Elastic Search as a sink to stream data from my application using Kafka Connectors. I am able to see the messages in Kafka, but my connector keeps throwing this error below:

```
    ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=elasticsearch-sink-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:179)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Couldn't start ElasticsearchSinkTask due to connection error:
    at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.jest.JestElasticsearchClient.<init>(JestElasticsearchClient.java:159)
    at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.jest.JestElasticsearchClient.<init>(JestElasticsearchClient.java:142)
    at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkTask.start(ElasticsearchSinkTask.java:122)
    at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkTask.start(ElasticsearchSinkTask.java:51)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.initializeAndStart(WorkerSinkTask.java:300)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:189)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:177)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:227)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: io.searchbox.client.config.exception.CouldNotConnectException: Could not connect to http://elasticsearch:9200
    at io.searchbox.client.http.JestHttpClient.execute(JestHttpClient.java:73)
    at io.searchbox.client.http.JestHttpClient.execute(JestHttpClient.java:63)
    at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.jest.JestElasticsearchClient.getServerVersion(JestElasticsearchClient.java:247)
    at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.jest.JestElasticsearchClient.<init>(JestElasticsearchClient.java:151)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to elasticsearch:9200 [elasticsearch/172.20.0.7] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:159)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:359)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:381)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:237)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:111)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108)
    at io.searchbox.client.http.JestHttpClient.executeRequest(JestHttpClient.java:136)
    at io.searchbox.client.http.JestHttpClient.execute(JestHttpClient.java:70)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:75)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
    ... 26 more
[2020-09-22 08:16:32,656] ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=elasticsearch-sink-0} Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:180)
```

I have dockerised everything, I have 4 containers one for my application, one for elasticsearch and one for kafka and one for a connector, as shown below:

```
zookeeper:
    container_name: zookeeper
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper:latest
    env_file:
      - ".env"
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
    networks:
      - "main_net"

  kafka:
    container_name: kafka
    image: wurstmeister/kafka:2.11-1.0.2
    env_file:
      - ".env"
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    links:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
      - 9094:9094
    networks:
      - "main_net"

  connector_standalone:
    container_name: container_standalone
    build:
      context: kafka/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - kafka
    ports:
      - 8083:8083
    networks:
      - "main_net"

elasticsearch:
    container_name: elasticsearch
    build:
      context: elasticsearch/
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
    env_file:
      - ".env"
    environment:
      discovery.type: single-node
    networks:
      - "main_net"

website:
    container_name: "application"
    build: "./"
    command: >
    volumes:
      - "./application:/app"
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    networks:
      - "main_net"
```

As far as I understood, I have given the connection URL, based on the host it should connect to, which is the elasticsearch container. But I am confused based on the error whats wrong. The below is my configuration file:

```
name=elasticsearch-sink
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector
tasks.max=1
topics=vehicle
topic.index=vehicles
connection.url=http://elasticsearch:9200/
connection.user=elastic
connection.password=changeme
type.name=log
key.ignore=true
schema.ignore=true
```

Comment: What version of Apache Kafka, the connector plugin, and Elasticsearch are you using? Is your topic actually called `logs`?

Comment: FWIW you can find a working example of Kafka -> Elasticsearch using Docker Compose here: https://rmoff.dev/kafka-elasticsearch (accompanying video: https://rmoff.dev/kafka-elasticsearch-video)

Comment: My bad!  I have updated with the correct topic name.

Comment: What version of Apache Kafka, the connector plugin, and Elasticsearch are you using?

Comment: BTW if you edit your question to change the error then it's good practice to note this in the comments! I only just realised you modified it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's failing because of this

```
Connect to elasticsearch:9200 [elasticsearch/172.20.0.7] failed: Connection refused
```

So either Elasticsearch is not up yet, or it is but not accepting connections.

Before creating your Kafka Connect connector make sure that Elasticsearch is available from your Kafka Connect worker by running this

```
docker exec connector_standalone curl -sS elasticsearch:9200/
```

You should get something like this back

```
{
  "name" : "216261a864bd",
  "cluster_name" : "docker-cluster",
  "cluster_uuid" : "tGHje8KSTPiafT7CLt77uQ",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.6.2",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "docker",
    "build_hash" : "ef48eb35cf30adf4db14086e8aabd07ef6fb113f",
    "build_date" : "2020-03-26T06:34:37.794943Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.4.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

FWIW you can find a working example of Kafka -> Elasticsearch using Docker Compose [here](https://rmoff.dev/kafka-elasticsearch) ()

Comment: `{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"security_exception","reason":"missing authentication credentials for REST request [/]","header":{"WWW-Authenticate":"Basic realm=\"security\" charset=\"UTF-8\""}}],"type":"security_exception","reason":"missing authentication credentials for REST request [/]","header":{"WWW-Authenticate":"Basic realm=\"security\" charset=\"UTF-8\""}},"status":401}%` This is what  I get, but I have given the right username and password to which I am able to login too.

Comment: That's a different error from which you asked in your question. It keeps StackOverflow easy to navigate for others if you mark this as answered (which I believe it is for your original question) and then start a new one with the new error.